Short sci-fi story titled "Valor"
Many years ago, I read a short science fiction story about aliens who were beaming philosophy to us humans. The main protagonist of the story was an IT guy who lived in England but was visiting friends in Germany.  The alien philosophy, instead of revolving around good versus evil, like we humans see, revolve around three elements — valor, gentleness, and evil.
Can anybody help me locate this story?

If the author thought that ternary moral philosophies were very alien, they should have played a game of Dungeons and Dragons, which in certain editions has, basically, a quaternary moral philosophy. Or two to six intersecting ternary moral axes, with  "yes," "no" and "don't care" on each one, depending on how one looks at it.

And 4e could be argued to have five....

When I last played D&D, which was a while ago, there were only two moral axes (law-neutral-chaos and good-neutral-evil.)  Maybe they added some more.

@DavidMoews - The story isn't about moral axes, otherwise it would be about humans having only one (between good and evil). As one can see from the reference to sexes, it's about the moral trinary of the aliens versus the (purported) moral binary of humans: three irreconcilable moral positions or forces versus two. By that standard, Dungeons and Dragons has at times had anywhere from four to nine (good and evil count as two in the story, so either good, evil, law and chaos would count as four in Dungeons and Dragons, or all nine alignments would count separately).

There were three possible moral positions (alignments) in original D&D, which only had the law-neutral-chaos axis.

Thus why I said "in certain editions" in my original comment. The first edition had two or three, by the definitions used in the story. And 4th edition is even weirder, since it has five alignments, all of which are arguably incompatible among themselves, and which are mostly named according to the 3.5 labels.

This matches the story "Valour", by Chris Beckett (1999).  See this earlier question.  The protagonist, Victor, travels from Cambridge to Berlin; on the trip, he meets the philosopher Gruber,

Here comes Victor, hurtling through the stratosphere on the Lufthansa shuttle: a shy, thin young Englishman, half-listening to the recorded safety instructions.

...

“My name is Gruber,” says the elderly German, extending a large friendly hand. “Heinrich Gruber, I am a student of philosophy and philology. How about you?” 
“I’m a computer scientist.” 
“Really? Where?” 
“Silicon City – it’s outside Cambridge – but I’m taking a sabbatical in Berlin.” 

joins his friends,

They are bright, polite, smartly dressed young people, who Victor and Lizzie met when they spent a year in Cambridge. After the eccentric Gruber, who might at any time say something embarrassing, they seem very normal and unthreatening and easy to get along with. Victor shakes their hands and exchanges minor news. They take him out to their little electric car (fossil fuels are verboten in the new Green Berlin) and head off in the direction of their Schoneberg apartment where he is to stay till he has found accommodation of his own.

and later returns to Gruber, who explains to him the message from the aliens, who are called Cassiopeians, and their philosophy:

"You probably remember that the message contains a repetitive element? Every 422 days it repeats the same five-day-long passage known as the Lexicon, which turns out to be a ‘Teach Yourself’ guide to the language. The key to understanding it was when we discovered that part of the Lexicon consisted of co-ordinates for a spatial grid. When these were mapped out, they produced pictures. The Cassiopeians taught us the basics of their language by sending us pictures and accompanying each picture with the appropriate word or words..."

...

"Just as there are three sexes, three states of matter and three Modes of Being – Substance, Life and Soul – so there are three principles in the universe constantly at war: Gentleness, Valour and Evil. There can be no reconciliation between these three, no final resolution of their perpetual conflict, only temporary alliances. Those who hate Evil must surely hope for an alliance of Gentleness and Valour, full of contradictions though such an Alliance will inevitably be. But oftentimes in history it is Valour and Evil that come together against Gentleness and we see cruel, harsh and warlike nations, preoccupied with honour, indifferent to suffering."

